# How to get the display_name from the XML-RPC response in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, wordpress, xml-rpc

In my iPhone app I am accessing a WordPress powered blog using XML-RPC WordPress APIs, and I am fetching the userlists through a XML-RPC method `wp.getUsers` connection. This is all working fine and I got the response as below (`NSLog` output):

```
2012-07-24 11:13:19.317 projectABC[1465:207] (
        {
        "display_name" = "Ravi Interior Design";
        email = "info@xyz.com";
        nicename = abiqsd;
        registered = "2012-05-11 11:58:52 +0000";
        "user_id" = 15;
        username = abssid;
    },
        {
        "display_name" = "qqHeuer";
        email = "aheuer@xyz.com";
        nicename = adamhequer;
        registered = "2012-05-18 15:59:30 +0000";
        "user_id" = 44;
        username = adamhequer;
    },
        {
        "display_name" = "Asdasm Rseyses";
        email = "xyz@abc.net";
        nicename = adaqmraeyes;
        registered = "2012-06-02 18:51:06 +0000";
        "user_id" = 160;
        username = adaqmreyeqs;
    },
```

Now I need to store only **display_name** in an NSArray, but I am not getting how to extract only  **display_name** from the above XML-RPC response. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you printing is NSArray of Dictionaries,

```
NSLog(@"%@",[yourArray valueForKeyPath:@"display_name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

For array of Dictionaries.

```
int i;
NSMutableArray *display_name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(i=0;i<[Arr count];++i)
{
    [display_name addobject:[[Arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"display_name"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[Arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"display_name"]);
}
```